# Why solution of $x^2-y^2=702$ is invalid?

Tags: number-theory

If $x$ & $y$ are natural numbers then  the no. of ordered pairs $(x, y)$ satisfying $$x^2-y^2=702$$

my try: i factorized

$$702=2\times 3^2\times 13$$ so i got

$$(x-y)(x+y)=2\times 3^2\times 13$$

i don't know how to proceed from here? 
please help. my book says there is no solution

Answer (score 6):

As $x+y+(x-y)$ or $x+y-(x-y)$ is even for integer $x,y$

$x+y, x-y$ have the **same** parity

If both are odd, $x^2-y^2$ will be odd

If both are even $x^2-y^2$ will be divisible by $4$ unlike $702$